# Replace url's in a string with href links - for multiple address types

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using this solution for quite some time:

```
function linkify(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
}
```

however, this solution only converts certain type of url's in a string, does not even work with links like `www.google.com` (needs to start with `http://`)

Therefore I wanted to ask if there is a more proper solution, preferably one that can convert `google.com`; `mail.google.com`, or even `del.icio.us` as well as email adresses.

Am I looking for too much? We can see this happen in real time in most places - what is the correct route?

Comment: Regex.... Now you have 2 problems.

Comment: Since this is a pretty common ting, I wanted to get public opinion first. Currently a regex to solve this is way out of my league. Any kind of help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this regexr: http://www.regexr.com/39suh
Put the `http` etc in a matching group and require a `.` in the url. I'm sure this is not the most ideal solution but it works okay...

```
(\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/)?[A-Z0-9.]*\.[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_.|]+)
```

Comment: you could also directly check for all the Top Level Domains that exist but this would make the regex extremly long...

Comment: but then the structure changes - for instance this doens't work if you put www in there

Comment: put a www where exactly? The wwws in the regexr do work, don't they? Maybe I am misunderstanding you...

Comment: Maybe it's the best if you can provide me a cssdeck, codepen, jsfiddle or something along the lines to examplify

Comment: I changed you function a little and ended up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/0fwrkp7v/

Comment: BTW I just noticed the first link you provided. What is the difference of this with the very first link (in the original answer)?
Both looks okay, but the "." becomes problematic specially at the end of sentences. Most people don't use proper spacing after finishing a sentence -- which seemed quite risky to me -

Comment: The problem is that urls are defined by the dot in the middle. I do not see a better way to do this...